# Javascript pattern to break up long-running recursive function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, recursion

I have a long-running function that does a huge calculation: all the possible permutations of x n-sided dice and the probability of those outcomes.  For small x and n, the calculation is quick.  For large values (n = 100, x > 3), the calculation takes tens of seconds if not longer; meanwhile, the browser stalls.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
let dist = [];

// min and max are the minimum and maximum possible values 
// (if dice are all 1's or all their maximum values)
for (let i = min; i <= max; i++) {
    // initialize possible values of our distribution to 0
    dist.push([ i, 0 ]);
}

// total is the total outcome value so far
// dIndex is the index into the dice-array (diceList) for the die we're
//   currently applying to our total--the die we're "rolling"
function applyDie(total, dIndex) {
    if (dIndex === diceList.length) {
        dist[total - min][1]++;
        permutationsCount++;
        return;
    }

    // diceList is an array of integers representing the number of sides
    // for each die (one array element = one die of element-value sides)
    for (let i = 1; i <= diceList[dIndex]; i++) {
        applyDie(total + i, dIndex + 1);
    }
}

// kick off recursive call
applyDie(0, 0);
```

I want to add two functionalities:

1. Cancellation
2. Progress reporting

Cancellation will be easy (I can do it myself) once I have the async pattern in place, so I really only need help with progress reporting, or, more accurately, simply breaking the recursive pattern into chunks based on the `permutationsCount` variable. i.e.

```
/* ... */
permutationsCount++;
if (permutationsCount % chunkSize === 0) 
    /* end this chunk and start a new one */
```

I would prefer to use Javasciprt `Promises`, but I'm open to other suggestions.

Ideas?

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded, you either have to use a `WebWorker`  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) or simply do the work to the server and poll it for progress/completion using ajax.

Comment: I know JavaScript is single threaded, but using Promises, you can do some of the calculation, and add a `.then()` to the currently running Promise to continue the calculation once the chunk has finished.  Between those, though, the browser can do other things (events, update UI, etc), mimicking async behavior.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was assuming you were doing the calculation in JS on the client, are you doing the calculation on the server?

Comment: No, I'm doing it on the client.  The server is running on node.js anyway, so that wouldn't help much.  :)

Comment: You cannot do the work on the client (without using a `WebWorker`) if the browser is hanging - promises don't change the fact that JavaScript is single threaded. Either do the work on a `WebWorker` on the server.

Comment: Use web workers, your example is exactly what web workers where created for :)

Comment: `setTimeout(applyDie.bind(this, total + i, dIndex + 1), i * 33);`

Comment: What dandavis said, I think is easiest way

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I wrote to do something similar. It's for a calculation done entirely in javascript... I couldn't tell from your question whether you were working entirely on the client side or what.

```
// Break the list up into equal-sized chunks, applying f() to each item of
// the list, writing a %-complete value to the progress span after each
// chunk. Then execute a callback with the resulting data.
var chunkedLoop = function (list, f, progressSpan, callback) {
    var numChunks = 10,
        chunkSize = Math.round(list.length / numChunks),
        chunkedList = [],  // will be a list of lists
        // Concatenated results of all chunks, passed to the callback.
        resultList = [],
        x,  // just a loop variable
        chunkIndex = 0;  // tracks the current chunk across timeouts

    progressSpan.html(0);

    // Splice of chunks of equal size, but allow the last one to be of an
    // arbitrary size, in case numChunks doesn't divide the length of the
    // list evenly.
    for (x = 0; x < numChunks - 1; x += 1) {
        chunkedList.push(list.splice(0, chunkSize));
    }
    chunkedList.push(list);

    // Schedule a series of timeouts, one for each chunk. The browser
    // stops blocking for a moment between each chunk, allowing the screen
    // to update. This is the only way to have progress values reported to
    // the view mid-loop. If it was done in a single loop, execution would
    // block all the way to the end, and the screen would only update once
    // at 100%.
    var chunkFunction = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            // Run f on the chunk.
            var chunk = chunkedList[chunkIndex];
            var r = forEach(chunk, f);
            resultList = resultList.concat(r);
            chunkIndex += 1;

            // Update progress on the screen.
            progressSpan.html(Math.round(chunkIndex / numChunks * 100));

            // Schedule the next run, if this isn't the last chunk. If it
            // is the last chunk, execute the callback with the results.
            if (chunkIndex < chunkedList.length) {
                chunkFunction();
            } else if (callback instanceof Function) {
                callback.call(undefined, resultList);
            }
        // There's no reason to delay more than the minimum one
        // millisecond, since the point is just to break up javascript's
        // single-threaded blocking.
        }, 1);
    };

    chunkFunction();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For reporting status you can pass callback function into your recursuve function and do there whatever you like (increase counter, push status into page etc).

Also think about rewriting recursive into iterative algorithm because it will have lesser memory overhead and it will be much easier to put there some other logic (like cancellations you mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setTimeout` to let JavaScript do other things and unstuck the event loop. This way even infinite loop would nonblocking. Here is a quick dirty example.

http://jsfiddle.net/xx5adut6/

```
function isPrime(n) {

    // If n is less than 2 or not an integer then by definition cannot be prime.
    if (n < 2) {
        return false
    }
    if (n != Math.round(n)) {
        return false
    }

    var isPrime = true;

    for (var i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            isPrime = false
        }
    }

    // Finally return whether n is prime or not.
    return isPrime;
}

var cancel = false;
var i = 0;
var primesFound = 0;
var status = $('.status');
var timeout;

function loop4Primes() {
    if (cancel) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        return;
    }
    if (isPrime(i++)) primesFound++;
    timeout = setTimeout(loop4Primes, 1);
}

function updateText() {
    status.text(primesFound);
}

var interval = setInterval(updateText, 1000);

$('#start').click(function () {
    loop4Primes();
    $(this).off('click');
});

$('#stop').click(function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
    updateText();
    cancel = true;
});
```